# Facebook app review process to access feeds from public page

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-requests

As a company we are developing apps for multiple clients, one of the apps common feature is access to their public page facebook feeds.

We have created separate Apps on our facebook account for each of our client.

As per the review response we need to submit for the business verification,

So my question is if we complete business verification for our company only, will that work or we need to complete verification for each one of our clients?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your App, so you only need business verification of your own company. Other companies will just use your App, but they are not responsible for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @luschn, one more query, all the apps are published to the app store / play store using clients developer accounts, and we are invited as admin to the accounts. So is it fine in this case as well?

Comment: that is something you would have to ask a lawyer, i guess ;)

Comment: :) Verified business now waiting for "Tech Provider Amendment" agreement email, once we complete that, we will submit app for review again, lets see what happens. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Submitted app for review after review completed business verification process by signing "Technology Provider Amendment" and accepted "Supplemental Terms".